# SqlCommand closing connections properly

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection

I have been working on an old project recently. I found in the project that previous colleagues have created some common methods to use for to open connection to database. But I have a doubt about the process whether it really handles connection by IDispose once the query completes.

Here is the methods:

Connect database.

```
/// <summary>
///     This method creates a connection object to the database.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>a new SQL Connection</returns>
public SqlConnection ConnectDB()
{
    var db = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    db.Open();
    return db;
} 

public SqlDataReader GetDataReader(SqlCommand query)
{
    var db = ConnectDB();
    query.Connection = db;
    var reader = query.ExecuteReader();
    return reader;
}
```

Then we use GetDataReader as below

```
var queryProduct= new SqlCommand
{
    CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT ProductName FROM Products"
};   

using (var reader = Interaction.GetDataReader(queryProduct))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
         var b = new Product
         {
              ProductName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ProductName"))
         };
         products.Add(b);
    } 
}
```

Do you think this process would release all the connection correctly?

Comment: No. Closing the reader doesn't mean that the command or the connection are closed. Even if it did, any exception before opening the reader will leave the connection open.  Why don't you use the typical approach - wrap the connection, command and reader in using statements?

Comment: If you execute your reader using `query.ExecuteReader(CommandBehaviour.CloseConnection)` then the connection will be closed when the reader is closed (which will happen when it is disposed). However, it is better to use using statements. It's clearer what the code is doing and ensures things are properly disposed and not just closed.

Comment: Check the documentation's example for [SqlDataReader.ExecuteReader(CommandBehaviour)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wy5a0f(v=vs.110).aspx) to see how to call `ExecuteReader` safely *and ensure* the connection is closed even if an exception occurs. You'll notice that the example is a lot simpler than your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code isn't safe. Disposing/closing the reader doesn't automatically close the connection, as you may want to execute multiple commands on the same connection. Even if you use [the override](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wy5a0f(v=vs.110).aspx) that *does* close the connection, exceptions that may occur before you enter the `using` block will leave the connection open.

The typical way is to wrap the connection, command and reader in `using` statements:

```
using(var con=new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var command=new SqlCommand(sql,con))
{
    con.Open();
    using(var reader=command.ExecuteReader())
    {
    ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Should I also passCommandBehavior.CloseConnection to ExecuteReader() method?

Comment: You don't have to because the connection is closed explicitly by the outer `using`.

Answer (score 1):

`SqlConnection` also implements `IDisposable` interface, so you have to close the connection too. So you should also wrap the connection in `using` block.

Answer (score 0):

No, your code doesn't release all the connections correctly as they have confirmed in other answers. 
Whereas modify an old program can be a nightmare I suggest an approach like this

```
class Program
{
    static IEnumerable<SqlDataReader> InteractionGetData(string query)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        yield return reader;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var reader in InteractionGetData("SELECT DISTINCT ProductName FROM Products"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ProductName")));
        }
    }
}
```